# How to improve performance when XORing large byte arrays

Tags: java, android, encryption, xor

I'm encrypting contents of a file by XORing it with a static key. Encrypting the contents varies from 100s to 200s on different android devices. Is there any way to speed up the process. Is there a way to speed up XORing bits?

```
  byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 1024];
  byte[] cryptKey = AppUtil.KEY.getBytes();
  int len;

            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                byte[] encryptedText = new byte[1024 * 1024];
                for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
                    encryptedText[i] = (byte) (buf[i] ^ cryptKey[i % AppUtil.KEY_SIZE]);
                }
                out.write(encryptedText, 0, len);
            }
```

Since I'm working with arrays of byte, will it be better if i write this code in native? Also is there a better way than this.

Please do not suggest using AES or other algorithms. I'm not concerned with securing data, just preventing regular users from accessing specific directories of the app

Comment: You allocate 1 MB for each in.read(buf) .. don't do that. You properbly want the allocation outside your read loop

Comment: Why are you creating a new `encryptedText` array for every call to `in.read()`? Wouldn't it make more sense to reuse the same array until the input file is exhausted. I suspect you're spending a lot of time performing unnecessary garbage collection to dispose of these arrays. And like @EbbeM.Pedersen says, there's no way the XOR operations could be to blame